# My function return last list has an error

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell, and I intended to code a function that would return to last list 2.

```hs
lastButOne x = if ((==) (length x) 2)
               then (head x)
               else (tail x)
```

this is error:

```
    ‧ Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
    ‧ In the expression: (tail x)
      In the expression:
        if ((==) (length x) 2) then (head x) else (tail x)
      In an equation for ‘lastButOne’:
          lastButOne x = if ((==) (length x) 2) then (head x) else (tail x)
    ‧ Relevant bindings include
        x :: [a] (bound at D:\\tool\8.6.3\test\lBoErr.hs:1:12)
        lastButOne :: [a] -> a (bound at D:\\tool\8.6.3\test\lBoErr.hs:1:1)

  |
3 |                            else (tail x)
  |                                  ^^^^^^
```

I do not understand where my code is wrong and what the error meant.

Comment: What type should the function `lastButOne` be? This might help you see what the problem is.

Comment: I agree, this error message is a bit cryptic. You can see the fundamental problem though if you look up the type signatures of [head](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head) and [tail](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#tail). One returns a single element, the other a list. GHC's error message is basically complaining that it's trying, and obviously failing, to find a type which can be both of those at once.

Comment: Adding an explicit type signature `lastButOne :: [a] -> ...` would have helped the compiler in identifying the issue, and providing a better error message. It is strongly recommended to start writing a function from its type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lastButOne` has intended type `[a] -> a`, but with `tail x` you are trying to return a value of type `[a]`. The error message results from the type checker's attempt to find a type which unifies with both `a` and `[a]`, in an attempt to make sense of a function that returns one or the other depending on which branch is taken.

What you want to do is *recurse* on the tail of the list:

```
lastButOne x = if length x == 2
               then head x
               else lastButOne (tail x)
```

This is more naturally written using pattern matching, though.

```
lastButOne [x,_] = x  -- lists of length exactly 2
lastButOne (_:xs) = lastButOne xs -- All other non-empty lists
```

Note `lastButOne` simply is not defined for empty or singleton lists, and will produce a run-time error if called on such. You can fix that by altering the return to `Maybe a`:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> Maybe a
lastButOne [x,_] = Just x
lastButOne (_:xs) = lastButOne xs
lastButOne _ = Nothing
```

Comment: I understand what you say.
Bacause my function use "head" and "tail" simultaneously, lead to ghci type check confusion.
I use recurse becase it a easy and obviously methon to achieve.
when I learn Lisp, recurse is regular.
can you tell me situation about haskll?
And thanks your response.

Comment: Possibly even more so than in Lisp, recursion is your *only* option for any type of iterative computation.